# Maven not working after updating java

Tags: jdk, maven-3

I have recently updated my java version to jdk7u9 in my ubuntu 11.04 Natty after which my previous maven projects have stopped working. I have installed using this [script](https://github.com/jvassev/install-jdk/)

When I run maven install in my projects (which previously used to work fine) I get this error

```
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Error configuring: com.company.build:maven-jsmodule-plugin. Reason: A required class was missing during mojo configuration: com/sun/tools/javac/util/Pair
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:723)

 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.util.Pair
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
```

I have tried googling the issue but all i get is setting the JAVA_HOME variable which is correct. Can anybody please help?

My maven version 2.2.1

Comment: You're running an unsupported configuration. I'd suggest getting rid of Horracle JDK, installing the latest `openjdk-7-jdk` package, and using that instead.